# Error while sending email through outlook in power shell script

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I have a powershell script as below. Here I check whether any .err file has been created before 5 minutes and if yes, then I am sending an email for each error file with first 5 lines of the .err file.When I try to run the script I receive an email for the first file, but i get an error for the second file as shown in the snapshot below. I am new to powershell, and I am struggling to find any solution for this error.

```
$ChkFile = "D:\ErrorLog\*.err"
$ChkFilePath = "D:\ErrorLog"
$o = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)
$mail.importance = 2
$mail.subject = “Error Log“
$mail.To = “email@email.com“
$FileExists = Test-Path $ChkFile
$FileCount = Get-ChildItem $ChkFilePath *.err | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
If ($FileExists -eq $True) {

    If ($FileCount -gt 0)
    {
         Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $ChkFile))
         {

             Write-Host $file
             $createtime = $file.LastWriteTime
             $nowtime = get-date
             if (($nowtime - $createtime).totalminutes -gt 5) 
             {
                $GetFileContent = Get-Content $file -totalcount 5
                $mail.body = $GetFileContent 
                Write-Host $GetFileContent 
                $mail.Send()

             }


         }


    }
}
```

Error generated while executing the script:
[image]

Comment: You could have checked `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you invoke the `$mail.Send()` method you will likely need to recreate your mail object. You could do this by placing the object creation in the loop.

```
$ChkFile = "D:\ErrorLog\*.err"
$ChkFilePath = "D:\ErrorLog"
$o = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$FileExists = Test-Path $ChkFile
$FileCount = Get-ChildItem $ChkFilePath *.err | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
If ($FileExists -eq $True) {

    If ($FileCount -gt 0) {
     Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $ChkFile)) {
         Write-Host $file
         $createtime = $file.LastWriteTime
         $nowtime = get-date
         if (($nowtime - $createtime).totalminutes -gt 5) {
            $mail = $o.CreateItem(0)
            $mail.importance = 2
            $mail.subject = "Error Log"
            $mail.To = "email@email.com"
            $mail.importance = 2
            $mail.subject = "Error Log"
            $mail.To = "email@email.com"
            $GetFileContent = Get-Content $file -totalcount 5
            $mail.body = $GetFileContent 
            Write-Host $GetFileContent 
            $mail.Send()

         }
     }
  }
}
```